# Is there way to detect formula with help of genetic algorithm?

Tags: genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

I am trying to find how two images (let's say "image1" and "image2") match to each other.
There are several parameters calculated for each possible position of "image2" relative to "image1". And I have empirical formula which gives "score" to each position depending on those parameters.

I tried to match image pars with help of neural networks, but failed : empirical formula works much better. From this I started thinking about to improve this formula with help of genetic algorithm.

So, the question is : I have a bunch of image pairs and for each pair I know "right" match position. Is genetic algorithm can be used in such things ? Any examples ?

Suggestions and links are appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, yes! The parameters of your score function could be the parameters that your GA is going to evolve. You may want to use a real coded genetic algorithm or evolution strategy (CMA-ES) if your parameters are in the real domain.

There exist several possible choices for crossover:

- Average / Intermediate
- Blend-Alpha (BLX-a)
- Blend-Alpha-Beta (BLX-a-b)
- Discrete
- Heuristic
- Local
- Random Convex
- Simulated Binary (SBX)
- Single Point

And also some mutation operators:

- Normal distributed N(0, sigma) -> e.g. with adaptation to reduce sigma over time
- Uniform distributed (in some positions)
- Polynomial mutation

Another metaheuristic suitable for real coded problems is particle swarm optimization (PSO).

With genetic programming you're going to evolve a formula (e.g. a tree). I'm not so sure why you mention it, maybe I still misunderstand something. Clarify your problem, just in case.

EDIT:

Okay it seems it's not the weights that you want to optimize, but the whole formula. Still, genetic algorithms can be used for this representation as well. I want to mention [HeuristicLab](http://dev.heuristiclab.com) due to its good support for genetic programming.

I assume you have a more complex problem since you want to optimize the scoring function, and still have another algorithm for optimizing the placement according to that scoring function. You could try an easy approach and generate a dataset with several positions predefined and the features calculated accordingly. Then you could formulate a classification problem and find a model that allows you to identify those positionings that are optimal.

Comment: I took watchmaker library, made some dirty-programming: implemented formula mutator and formula crossower, add two simple functions (so, formula consist of those functions with parameters which are mutating), added fitness function, etc.  The results are not so bad that I expected (taking into account that I used dirty-approach to make PoC). Approach with GA looks for me more attractive, more predictable and more understandable than neural networks (which I tried to used before). Have a nice day!

Comment: just to make sure that you understand my problem: I need a formula which will fulfill some "matching" between image pair (this matching depends on parameters). By long series of experiments I got empirical formula, but now I wanted to improve this empirical formula. And GA approach works for me: generated/mutated formulas which I received from GA runs are not worse than my original (not surprisingly, they looks often very different than mine). However, as I said they works too. Will introduce more functions to formula, expecting this may give GA change to evolve very good candidate :)

Comment: You could also implement your evaluation function in [HeuristicLab](http://dev.heuristiclab.com) which already has GP and an extensible tree-based encoding implemented. There's a detailed [howto](http://dev.heuristiclab.com/trac/hl/core/wiki/UsersHowtosImplementGeneticProgrammingProblems) on how to implement genetic programming problems.